# Save grid move and resize value into state and session

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I want to save state values into database not in cookies. Whenever particular page load again, i wanted it to load data from state into grid. For example, If user drag and drop column, position and save into database, or if change column width, width and save into database for future use.

Please anyone guide me, how to manage STATE????

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IF you like to persist in database and render the persisted column position, then you need to config the column as dynamically. Please refer below sample example for reference

```
// below array of object should be formatted from database and assing to variable columnpos.


var columnPos = [
    { text: 'Name1',  dataIndex: 'name', width:100 },
    { text: 'Email1', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 , width:200},
    { text: 'Phone1', dataIndex: 'phone', width:300 }
    ]

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: columnPos,
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Thanks, This will work.